# Insert dates for next 7 days in BigQuery

Tags: date, google-bigquery

I have a dataset and I have to insert a date column with next 7 days date in it. How do I do it?

```
SELECT invite_date
FROM UNNEST(
    GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(current_date(), DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL 7 DAY), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
) AS invite_date
```

The above query returns dates of 7 days. How do I insert each row with any of these dates with equal number of row having each date

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help:

```
WITH sample_data AS (
SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
      STRUCT<one STRING, two INT64, three FLOAT64, four DATE>
      ("a", 2018, 0.1, '2022-12-01'),
      ('b', 2017, 1.1, '2022-11-01'),
      ('c', 2016, 5.2, '2022-10-01'),
      ('d', 2015, 4.9, '2022-09-01')
  ]))

SELECT *, GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(CURRENT_DATE(), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY), interval 1 DAY) AS invite_date

FROM sample_data
```